# problem with gradient descent method for simple convex optimization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

For my practice, I am trying to solve the following simple convex optimization by using the gradient descent method for the Lagrangian function of the objective function:

Minimize $x^2$

s.t.  $x\leq2$

I formulate the Lagrangian as follows

$\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)=x^2+\lambda(x-2)$, with $\lambda\geq0$

I start gradient method for Lagrangian function with $x=2, \lambda=0.1$, and in every iteration of the gradient descent method I update $x$ and $\lambda$ as follows:

$x=x-t(2x+\lambda)$

$\lambda=\lambda-t(x-2)$; if $\lambda$ gets negative, I change it to $\lambda=0$

where $t$ is the step size. I have tried using exact line search and also backtracking line search in every iteration to find the $t$ and used it in the equations. But I don't get the convergence and the result at all. I am wondering where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't followed the recipe for constructing the dual problem correctly. You must first find the dual function $G$ which is defined by $G(\lambda) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb R} L(x,\lambda)$, where $L(x,\lambda) = x^2 + \lambda(x - 2)$. Once you have found $G$, the dual problem is to maximize $G(\lambda)$ subject to the constraint that $\lambda \geq 0$. If you're not already reading [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), it spells out the dual problem construction pretty clearly.

Comment: @littleO Thanks, you are right. In fact I did not explained what I meant, correctly. I revised my question. I do not want to obtain $G(\lambda)$, because finding the $\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)$ in general (for different objective functions) is not easy and I want to use gradient descent method to obtain optimal $x$ (my main problem is something else and I did not mention it here for simplicity. I am trying to solve this simple problem and then apply the same method for more complicated objective functions).

Comment: (1) you have a wrong sign in the update of $\lambda$, and (2) the step size $t$ for the update of $\lambda$ should be fixed and has nothing to do with the step size used to update $x$. Your algorithm should then converge whether you use exact like search or a sufficiently small fixed step size for the $x$ updates

Comment: "I start with gradient method for the Lagrangian" This doesn't make sense, because $(x^\star,\lambda^\star)$ is not a minimizer for the Lagrangian. So why try to minimize $L$ with respect to $x$ and $\lambda$ using gradient descent? Rather, $(x^\star, \lambda^\star)$ is a saddle point of the Lagrangian. Instead of gradient descent, you could use a primal-dual method such as the Arrow-Hurwicz method, which alternates between gradient descent steps with respect to $x$ and gradient ascent steps with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: @Bananach You are right, I changed the sign of $\lambda$ updates and used fixed $t=.01$ for both and it converged fast. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @littleO Thanks for your suggestion. I will check that algorithm. As I mentioned in the previous comment, the changes I made solved the problem; in fact I think it is similar to what you suggest, as the updates of $x, \lambda$ seem to be now based on gradient descent and gradient ascent.

Comment: Yeah, with that change you are now using the Arrow-Hurwicz method.

Comment: @Bananach  I also tried line search for the step sizes of $x$ and .01 for step sizes of $\lambda$. It converged very slowly and with a lot of oscillations.

Comment: @Cror assuming youre doing an exact line search, that should be equivalent to doing gradient descent on $G$ (instructive exercise: show that in this case, the partial derivative of the Lagrangian is equal to the derivative of $G$), so I would be surprised that it's slow.

Comment: @Bananach The dual function is $G(\lambda) = -\lambda^2/4 - 2\lambda$, so $G'(\lambda) = -\lambda/2 - 2$. The gradient ascent iteration on the dual problem would be $\lambda^{k+1} = \max(\lambda^k + t(-\lambda^k/2 - 2),0)$. The algorithm that OP is currently using, which alternates between gradient descent steps with respect to $x$ and gradient ascent steps with respect to $\lambda$, has a similar $\lambda$ update $\lambda^{k+1} = \max(\lambda^k + t(x^k - 2), 0)$, but the $\lambda$ update involves $x^k$. So the algorithm OP is using isn't equivalent to gradient ascent on the dual problem.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe with exact line search $x^k$ turns out to be equal to $-\lambda^k/2$. I need to think about that a little more.

Comment: It is. And that's not just a coincidence of this particular function

Comment: @Bananach I have another problem that I am working on now. It is difficult to find the dual objective function so I want to use the Lagrangian function and prima-dual method. I wanted to see if you know of a good source for Arrow-Hurwicz method. Also,  how should I do line search in primal-dual problem? Should I do separate line search and use different step sizes for primal and dual variables by finding $t_x= \arg \min_t \mathcal{L}(x+t\Delta x,\lambda) , t_{\lambda}= \arg \min_t \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda+t\Delta \lambda)$ ?

Comment: @littleO I have got another problem, and I need to find a good detailed explanation of Arrow-Hurwicz method to apply to that problem. Do you know of a good source for this method? I want to know what are the update steps in general problems.

Comment: Read any book on convex optimization. People might not call it Arrow -Hurwicz though

Comment: @Bananach Yes, I did not find the name of Arrow-Hurwicz, even when I google the name I don't get good results. Anyway, thanks. Could you please also let me know about second part of my question, i.e., line search?

Comment: Read books and articles. No need to repeat here what's hundredfold and better out there